# Example for specific date format

Tags: php, date

> Hi this is my date format "Month/yyyy" please provide an example of
>   date for this format i want to parse date to this format

Comment: `date('m/Y')`  Here is a list of all date formats.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: orcale cloud customer support said that i should send the value of the field in such format "Month/yyyy" , i converted it to date('m/Y') ordate('M/Y') but it doesn't work i'm getting wrong data type(response)

Answer (score 0):

Use the strtotime() and date() functions:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

```
$date = '2018-06-07';    
echo date('m/Y', strtotime($date));
```

Comment: orcale cloud customer support said that i should send the value of the field in such format "Month/yyyy" , i converted it to date('m/Y') ordate('M/Y') but it doesn't work i'm getting wrong data type(response) –

Comment: "m" is the month with a leading "0"  like "06".   "n" is the month without a leading "0"  like "6".  That could make a difference.  Check oracles syntax for date handling.  It could be an entire other problem.  Without a better description of the error and a better example of the code we are probably not going to be able to help you.